# Update fields with post object and custom tax with wp_insert_post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-insert-post, post-meta

**Updated Post**
'**update_field**' Function is **Acf** Plugin

```
$supplier_one = 'my supplier';
$supplier_two = 'my supplier TWO';
$post_id_one = 555;
$post_id_two = 556;

update_field('suppliers', $supplier_one, $post_id_one)
update_field('suppliers', $supplier_two, $post_id_two)
```

This code works for post object?
My other question is how to send posts to custom taxonomies with wp_insert_post
My Code for Wp_insert_post

```
$insert_post = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'post_title' => 'my post title',
    'tax_input' => array( 'category-products' => array( 'several' ) ) /// Category for post_type products
);
wp_insert_post($insert_post);
```

Comment: What is `update_field()`? It's not WordPress core function. Also please ask separate questions for separate issues.

Comment: Sorry bro, updated.